# CSS Darken on Hover without Changing Text Color

Tags: css

I'm looking to darken an element on hover **without** also darkening the text color. I would like the text to remain pure white on hover.

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="badge" style="background-color: #0072CE;"><span>Some Text</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 0.65em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.badge:hover {filter: brightness(0.8);}
.badge > span {color: white;}
```

I tried applying positioning and `z-index` but that didn't work either. Also, I need the `style` tag because the background colors are generated dynamically.

Any help on the above or a different solution altogether would be appreciated!

EDIT: My appologies, I should have been clear that I also don't have access to set the hover color in the styles.

Comment: Backdrop-filter is all you need

Comment: This actually seems like a specificity issue between your inline styles and your style tag

Comment: backdrop-filter doesn't work on Firefox and was hoping to find a complete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using filter: Brightness(), I prefer to use filter: Saturate().
It gives object darken background but doesn't affect your text.

```css
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 0.65em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* .badge:hover {filter: brightness(0.8);} */
.badge:hover {filter: saturate(0.5);}
.badge > span {color: white;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="badge" style="background-color: #0072CE;"><span>Some Text</span></a>
```

Comment: Interesting solution ngl

Comment: Perfect! This works great, and I can remove the span tags too. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that just works with white or black text color.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I can think of right now when you're unable to change the inline styling.

Essentially styling the span instead, changing *it's* background opacity based on hover.

```css
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.badge>span {
  display: block;
  padding: .35em .65em;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.badge>span:hover {
  background-color: #0004;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="badge" style="background-color: #0072CE;"><span>Some Text</span></a>
```

Comment: I don't have access to set the hover color in the stylesheet. Otherwise, I wouldn't be using inline styles at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use background-color attribute to change the background color

```
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 0.65em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(111,111,111,1);
}
.badge:hover {background-color: rgba(111,111,111,.5);}
```

you can make background color transparent with value of alpha in rgba(r, g, b, alpha)

or

you can just change background color

Comment: This won't work because the inline style has higher specificity and will always override the style tag styling.